# error when add element at specified index in ArrayList [Java]

Tags: java, arrays, oop, arraylist

I have an error when adding an element at the specified index in `ArrayList` I'm using loop and variable it's increasing every time when looping

1. **I tried** to use a command `arrayListName.add(index,thing)` but this give me an error when assign second time 
   problem ==> https://ibb.co/ZSQvywY .
2. **I tried** to loop without index but this all the time assign in index [0]

```java
public class CollegeSystem {

    public static void printOptions() {
        System.out.println("Welcome to our university!");
        System.out.println("Operations:");
        System.out.println("1- College");System.out.println("a) Number of Departments");System.out.println("b) Number of Courses");System.out.println("c) Number of Professors");System.out.println("d) Number of Students");System.out.println("e) Report");
        System.out.println("2- Department");System.out.println("a) New");System.out.println("b) Number of Courses");System.out.println("c) Number of Students");System.out.println("d) Is Full");System.out.println("e) Enroll");System.out.println("f) Report");
        System.out.println("3- Course");System.out.println("a) New");System.out.println("b) Number of Students");System.out.println("c) Assign");System.out.println("d) Is assigned");System.out.println("e) Professor Name");System.out.println("f) Is Full");System.out.println("g) Enroll");System.out.println("h) Report");
        System.out.println("4- Professor");System.out.println("a) New");System.out.println("b) Display Salary");System.out.println("c) Get Raise");System.out.println("d) Report");
        System.out.println("5- Student");System.out.println("a) New");System.out.println("b) Report");
        System.out.println("6- Quit");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        printOptions() ;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in) ; 
        int d = 0 , c = 0  , p = 0 , s=0 ; 
        College AinShams = new College() ; 
        while (true){
            String option = in.nextLine() ; 
            if(!"6".equals(option)) {
                if ("2a".equals(option)) { // Define new department
                    System.out.println("Department Name:");
                    String depName = in.nextLine() ; 
                    System.out.println("Department Description:");
                    String depDescripe = in.nextLine() ;
                    System.out.println("Department Max Students:");
                    int max_num = in.nextInt() ;
                    in.nextLine() ; 
                    Department Department_Name = 
                    new Department(depName,   depDescripe, max_num); 
                    List<Department> departmentList;
                   //here create a new arrayList
                   departmentList = new ArrayList<>();
                 //try to add element without index
                   //  departmentList.add(Department_Name);
                 //try to add element with index
                   departmentList.add(d, Department_Name);
                    d++ ;
                    AinShams.setDepart(departmentList);      
                }
            }   
        }   
    } 
 }
```

I need to add an element in every time I loop without remove old data.

Comment: There are several issues with your code: (1) you always recreate `departmentList` and thus get an empty list, (2) if you want to add elements at the end, why not just call `add(element)`?, (3) read up on the Java Code conventions - that should make you realize that names like `Department_Name` are discouraged. It should be `departmentName` instead - and since the type is `Department` and not `String` (or whatever would be used to represent a name) just `department` might be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's always in index 0 has nothing to do with whether you pass an index or not.

```
while (true){
        String option = in.nextLine() ; 
        if(!"6".equals(option)) {
            if ("2a".equals(option)) { // Define new department
                ...
                List<Department> departmentList;
               //here create a new arrayList
               departmentList = new ArrayList<>();
             //try to add element without index
               //  departmentList.add(Department_Name);
             //try to add element with index
               departmentList.add(d, Department_Name);
                d++ ;
                ....

            }
        }
```

Each time you add an element, you add it in a newly created List. You should create the List before your loop, and just keep the add statements in there:

```
List<Department> departmentList = new ArrayList<>();
while (true){
        String option = in.nextLine() ; 
        if(!"6".equals(option)) {
            if ("2a".equals(option)) { // Define new department
                ...
             //try to add element without index
               //  departmentList.add(Department_Name);
             //try to add element with index
               departmentList.add(d, Department_Name);
                d++ ;
                ....

            }
        }
```